# How to get ISO 50 & 4 Sec Shutter speed on any Lumia running Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, camera

It is an interesting mod to “maximize potential of Camera” on Lumia devices running Windows 10 Mobile. Modders over XDA Forum have succeeded in altering the parameter values of Camera on a Lumia 730.

The mod gave Lumia 730 capability to shoot at *ISO 50 and with 4 Sec shutter speed*, normally only achievable on **PureView** devices. Above good looking image is result of custom settings.

Step by step instructions to do the mod is listed below. Do it at your own risk and if you know what you are doing.

Comment: the user who downvoted this, care to explain, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open [Custom PFD](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3478178&d=1442589534). (Its an app, you'll have to deploy it via SDK from PC)
2. Continue to HKLM\SOFTWARE\OEM\nokia\Camera
3. Choose FrontFacingCamera (FFC) or RearFacingCamera (RFC).
4. Continue to Caps.
5. If you want to set minimal ISO, select “+” and type Key: MinIso | value: less than 100 (example 50), and WRITE.
6. If you want to set maximal Shutter Speed, select “+” and type key: MaxET | value: 4000000 (more value dont work), and WRITE.
7. MaxIso for RFC is 3200 (if you set it more than that, it’ll not work).
8. All value must be Dword 32

> Recommended value of min iso is 50 (default), so you will get max iso upto 3200.
>   [image]

[image]

[image]

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10/windows-10-mobile/maximize-potential-lumia-win10m-camera-t3192960)